# Hamburger menu not showing when opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a website, implemented some things and now when I moved some elements and CSS around to organize and declutter, my hamburger menu stopped showing when opened. Instead of sliding down with a nice animation the nav-bar disappear and the menu doesn't show, if I inspect I can see that the menu is there but there is something covering it or some opacity being wrong. But I went trough all my z-index's and opacity's and there is nothing that is wrong, what I can see. So I would like some help with getting my hamburger menu to show when clicked to show.

The hamburger is only shown on mobile view FYI

I'll include a snippet down below but here is the code I think is causing the trouble:

```html
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-menu">
        <div class="burger-container">
          <div id="burger">
            <div class="bar topBar"></div>
            <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Hem</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/sakerhetshot.html">Säkerhetshot</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
          </li>
          <div class="flex-filler"></div>
          <li class="toggler-container">
            <div class="switcher">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> dark_mode </span>
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
                <span class="slider"></span>
              </label>
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> light_mode </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="parallax">
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/Kem93m.png" class="background" />
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/KemO9N.png" class="foreground" />
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Lagar och säkerhet</h1>
          <p>
            Hemsidan om lagar och säkerhet på internet här står det massa saker wow omg coolt :I
          </p>
        </div>
      </header>
```

```css
    .wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      perspective: 10px;
    }
    
    nav {
      overflow: hidden;
    
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    
      width: 100%;
    
      transition: 0.5s ease;
    
      background-color: var(--black-color);
    }
    
    .parallax {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      z-index: -10;
    }
    
    .background {
      transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
      -webkit-user-drag: none;
      user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .foreground {
      transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
      -webkit-user-drag: none;
      user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .background,
    .foreground {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      z-index: -10;
    }
    
    .hero-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: var(--white-color);
    
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    
      min-width: 14rem;
    
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .hero-text > h1 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    .hero-text > p {
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
    .burger-container {
      position: absolute;
      right: 1rem;
      top: 0.1rem;
    
      display: inline-block;
    
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
      user-select: none;
    
      z-index: 10;
    
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }
    
    #burger {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
    
      width: 18px;
      height: 8px;
    
      display: block;
    
      margin: -4px auto 0;
    }
    
    .bar {
      position: relative;
    
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
    
      display: block;
    
      background: var(--white-color);
    
      transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .topBar {
      transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    .btmBar {
      transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    
      padding: 0;
      background: var(--black-color);
      height: 100%;
    
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .menu-item {
      transform: translateY(-200px);
      transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
    }
    
    .menu-item a {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    
      color: var(--white-color);
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      line-height: 2.35;
    
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--body-bg-color);
    
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .menu-item a:hover {
      color: var(--text-hover-color);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .nav-menu {
      height: 3.5rem;
      transition: height 0.4s;
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened {
      transition: height 0.4s;
    
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 20;
    
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
      transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
      transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
      transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
    .nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
      transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    }
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hamburger
  $(".burger-container").click(function () {
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-opened");
    $("body").toggleClass("unscrollable");
  });

  // Dark-Light switcher
  $("body").toggleClass("light", localStorage.toggled == "light");

  document.getElementById("checkBox").addEventListener("click", darkLight);

  function darkLight() {
    if (localStorage.toggled != "light") {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", true);
      localStorage.toggled = "light";
    } else {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", false);
      localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
  }

  if ($("body").hasClass("light")) {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

// Scroll to top
button = document.getElementById("scroll-button");

button.addEventListener("click", topFunction);

window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Dark colors */
:root {
  --white-color: #d9d9d9;
  --black-color: #0d0d0d;

  --grey-color-1: #595959;

  --body-bg-color: #262626;

  --text-hover-color: #a6a6a6;
}

/* Light colors */
:root .light {
  --body-bg-color: #dfdfdf;

  --black-color: blue;
  --white-color: black;
}

/* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: var(--body-bg-color) !important;

  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

main {
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;

  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;

  transition: 0.5s ease;

  background-color: var(--black-color);
}

.unscrollable {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ======= PARALLAX ======= */

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -10;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -10;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--white-color);

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  min-width: 14rem;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-text > h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.hero-text > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */

.burger-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0.1rem;

  display: inline-block;

  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;

  z-index: 10;

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#burger {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;

  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;

  display: block;

  margin: -4px auto 0;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;

  display: block;

  background: var(--white-color);

  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  padding: 0;
  background: var(--black-color);
  height: 100%;

  list-style: none;
}

.menu-item {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;

  color: var(--white-color);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 2.35;

  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--body-bg-color);

  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 3.5rem;
  transition: height 0.4s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened {
  transition: height 0.4s;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 20;

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

/* ======== Dark Light switcher ====== */

.switcher > span {
  color: var(--white-color);
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.switcher {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggler-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.toggler-container {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;

  display: inline-block;

  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #808080;

  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;

  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;

  content: "";

  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;

  background-color: var(--white-color);

  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #808080;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  -ms-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  transform: translateX(1.7rem);
}

/* ======== CONTENT ======= */

.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

.img {
  display: block;
}

/* ======== UP ARROW ========*/

#scroll-button {
  display: none;

  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1.2rem;

  z-index: 10;

  border: none;
  outline: none;

  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;

  cursor: pointer;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* ======== FOOTER ======== */

footer {
  padding: 3rem 0 6rem 0;
  background-color: var(--grey-color-1);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -20;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

footer ul a {
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
}

footer ul a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

footer hr {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  max-width: 13rem;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
}

footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

/* ======== MEDIA QUERIES ======== */

/* TABLET */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 35rem;
  }
}

/* DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  /* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

  .hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    max-width: 20rem;
  }

  .hero-text > h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .hero-text > p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  /* ======= Scrollbar ======== */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;

    background: transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 100px;

    background: rgb(109, 109, 109);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgb(148, 148, 148);
  }

  /* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */

  .nav-menu {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;

    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .nav-menu.menu-opened {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .burger-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-item {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);

    display: inline;

    margin-right: 0.8rem;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    margin: 0 0 0 1.5rem;

    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    display: inline;

    border: none;

    font-size: 1rem;

    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.54, 0.94);
  }

  .flex-filler {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  /* ======== Dark-light switcher ======== */

  .toggler-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 2.5rem 0 0;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }

  .switcher > span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;

    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  .switch {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 1.3rem;
  }

  .slider:before {
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 0.8rem;

    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
  }

  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    -ms-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    transform: translateX(1.2rem);
  }

  /* ======== CONTENT ========*/

  .content {
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }

  .content h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .content p {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
  }

  /* ======== UP ARROW ========*/

  #scroll-button {
    position: fixed;

    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;

    bottom: 1.1rem;
    right: 1.1rem;
  }

  #scroll-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.568);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  }

  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
}

/* XL-DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* ======= HAMBURGER ======= */

  .menu-item {
    margin-right: 1.3rem;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Lagar och säkerhet | Hem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0"
    />
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!--
    Att göra: 
    
    Fixa bilder till Hero parallax
    Skriva content
    Fixa bilder till content (Picture element, bootstrap)
    Lägga in all content på index och subpages (Bootstrap)
    Fixa up arrow så den funkar
    Tablet responsive media query
    Hamburger close animation (Inte prio)
  -->
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-menu">
        <div class="burger-container">
          <div id="burger">
            <div class="bar topBar"></div>
            <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Hem</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/sakerhetshot.html">Säkerhetshot</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
          </li>
          <div class="flex-filler"></div>
          <li class="toggler-container">
            <div class="switcher">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> dark_mode </span>
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
                <span class="slider"></span>
              </label>
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> light_mode </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="parallax">
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/Kem93m.png" class="background" />
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/KemO9N.png" class="foreground" />
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Lagar och säkerhet</h1>
          <p>
            Hemsidan om lagar och säkerhet på internet här står det massa saker wow omg coolt :I
          </p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="content">
          <section>
            <h2>Hejehje</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni in aut quisquam ipsa,
              reiciendis quidem rem facilis quaerat nam est! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
              adipisicing elit. Libero, nulla perferendis? Officia illo vitae alias obcaecati nulla
              porro quisquam, praesentium id vel ex culpa deleniti neque reiciendis officiis nisi
              quaerat.
            </p>
          </section>
          <picture class="img">
            <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="imgs/template1000.jpg" />
            <img src="imgs/template500.jpg" alt="template500" />
          </picture>
        </div>
        <button id="scroll-button" title="Gå till toppen">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="active">Hem</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/sakerhetshot.html">Säkerhetshot</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; All rights reserved by Vincent Cornelius</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `nav` element has no height.  When the menu is opened by adding the `menu-opened` class it becomes `position: absolute` and has a fixed height, and the parent element has a height of 0 because it collapses.

My recommendation would be to add the `menu-opened` class on the `<nav>` element instead of on `.nav-menu`, and then in the CSS add:

```css
nav.menu-opened { 
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the position of nav-menu item, try to overwrite with

```
.nav-menu.menu-opened {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Thats bc when a element has a child with position absolute, the parent doesn't calculate it's height, so the parent container has height of zero